# create mobile menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a mobile menu using jQuery, but I'm having the following issue: mobile menu is only being displayed based on width I put @ media query, and when I click at one of the navigation links, they disappear as they should. But if I resize the window for full width, the navigation bar is completely hidden, and I can only see the logo. For the navigation menu to show up again I have to refresh the page. How can I fix that?

Here's the HTML for header

```html
   <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <i class="fas fa-code fa-3x"></i> 
        </div>

        <div class="mobile-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></div>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS for `mobile-menu` and media-query for both `mobile-menu` and `navbar`

```css
.mobile-menu {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    display: none;
}  
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){

    .mobile-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: var(--secondary);
        width: 11rem;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 60px;
    }
}
```

JS

```js
$('.mobile-menu').on('click', function () {
    $('.navbar').slideToggle();
});

$('.navbar').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the nav menu is not being shown as you resize back the window is that you call hide() method that adds inline (display: none) css style to your element.
To prevent that, I would advice you to add/remove additional css class to your navbar.
For example:

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .hidden {
    display:block; // Or whatever (flex, grid, etc.)
  }
}
```

Or:

Remove use show() at navbar at resize breakpoint.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var width = $(this).width()
  if (width > 768) {
    $(".navbar").show()
  }
})
```

Comment: OMG YOU'RE A TRUE LIFE SAVER!! I TRIED THE SECOND SOLUTION, AT FIRST IT DIDNT WORK, BUT THEN I DID THIS

```javascript

$(window).resize(function () {
  var width = $(this).width()
  if (width > 768) {
    $(".navbar").show()
  } else {
  $('nav ul li').click(function() {
   $('.navbar').hide()
  });
  
 }
})
```

and it seems to work! I'm testing but when the width is 768px or less, everything still working and when i resize window, the navigation now is showing!! THANK U SO MUCH, i dont know if its the right solution tho, but thats how it worked

Comment: yeah, so i did more tests and it has somebugs, sometimes the navigation bar disappears again and i still have to refresh

Comment: Use browser inspector to see that is happening with your menus. The point is that hide() method adds inline styles to your element that override your css classes styles.